# Error in TeamCity build only

Tags: visual-studio-2015, teamcity

```
public bool ReceiveBroadcastMessagesDone { get; set; } **= false;**
```

The above line built fine on my own box with Vs2015 but TeamCity errors on it -

> MulticastReceive.cs(49,64): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class,
>   struct, or interface member declaration -  [10:15:24][Step 15/19]

Removing the = false fixes it - any idea why?

TeamCity Server has Vs2015 and is runner type is a Visual Studio Solution.

My plan is to build locally on the TeamCity Build Machine and see if the error is present.

Comment: What is the build runner type and version being used on the build agent?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably down to the build runner / framework combination. You can use either MSBuild or Visual Studio with various version options.

Ensure you're using a Visual Studio build runner and version 2015 if you want the same comparability as building locally - This would require VS to be installed on the build agents if you went down this route.

Hope this helps